# Multi Header Sections in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The following code successfully populates a table as shown in **UITableView 1** image. What I would like to do is add an extra level, something that looks like **UITableView 2** image.

What would be the best way to create a multi-level section as shown in **UITableView 2** image?

FYI - I tried to follow the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650243/uitableview-nested-section-headers) thread but I couldn't make it work.

### CODE

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!
    
    let sections = [["Mustang", "Model S"],["F-150", "Cybertruck"]]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let viewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: myTable.frame.width, height: 40))
        viewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let labelHeader = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 200, height: 30))

        labelHeader.textColor = UIColor.white
        if section == 0{
            labelHeader.text = "Cars "
        }
        if section == 1{
            labelHeader.text =  "Trucks"
        }
        viewContainer.addSubview(labelHeader)
        return viewContainer
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0{
            return sections[section].count
        }
        return sections[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        }
        if indexPath.section == 1{
            cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

### IMAGES

[image]

Comment: Think a bit more about your question. Your 2nd image can easily be done with two custom cell classes.... but is that all you want? Or, do you want the "sub sections" to be scrollable with their headers sticky like the "main" section headers?

Comment: I was thinking that the subheaders could grow and scroll as normal in a tableView. There will be only two main headers, Cars and Trucks. The subheaders will be dynamic and can be a lot them (Ford, Tesla, Chevy, Toyota, Nissan etc.) and each subheader can have many car models (e.g for Ford you could have Mustang, Flex, Escort, Taurus, Fusion etc.) Are suggesting using two custom cells to put cars in one and trucks in the other one? Thanks

Comment: It would (likely) be confusing to try and have scrollable sections within scrollable sections... when should the "inner sections" scroll and when should the "outer sections" scroll? So, it depends what you want to do. Should the "Brand" rows be tappable / selectable? Only the "Model" rows? Do you want to expand/collapse the Model rows under the Brand rows? Are you intending to allow the user to select multiple Models?

Comment: Here is what I'm thinking, callapsable would only be the two main headers (Cars and Trucks). Selectable only the Models (Mustang, Model S etc.).  For scrolling I was hoping to be able to scroll everything at the same time as the standard behavior as in **UITableView 1** image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with a single Cell Prototype:

[image]

I've added a single label, constrained on all 4 sides (use margins).

You'll notice one of the constraints is not like the others - `Label Leading` - because I connected that as an `@IBOutlet`. When I set the cell data, I change the label background color, the `.constant` of the leading constraint, and the `.selectionStyle` based on it being a "Brand" row or a "Model" row:

```
enum VehicleType {
    case car, truck
}

struct Vehicle {
    var type: VehicleType = .car
    var brand: String = ""
    var model: String = ""
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var labelLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    func setData(_ v: Vehicle) -> Void {
        
        if v.model == "" {
            theLabel.text = v.brand
            theLabel.textColor = .darkGray
            theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
            labelLeading.constant = 0
            selectionStyle = .none
        } else {
            theLabel.text = v.model
            theLabel.textColor = .black
            theLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
            labelLeading.constant = 16
            selectionStyle = .default
        }

    }
    
}
```

In this example, I determine if it's a "Brand" row/cell if the "Model" name is an empty string.

Here's how it can look:

[image]

and after scrolling down to the Trucks section:

[image]

If you want other appearance differences between the Brand and Model rows, you can handle those in the same `.setData()` function.

Here is a complete example:

```
enum VehicleType {
    case car, truck
}

struct Vehicle {
    var type: VehicleType = .car
    var brand: String = ""
    var model: String = ""
}

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var theLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var labelLeading: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    func setData(_ v: Vehicle) -> Void {
        
        if v.model == "" {
            theLabel.text = v.brand
            theLabel.textColor = .darkGray
            theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
            labelLeading.constant = 0
            selectionStyle = .none
        } else {
            theLabel.text = v.model
            theLabel.textColor = .black
            theLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
            labelLeading.constant = 16
            selectionStyle = .default
        }

    }
    
}

class MultiSectionViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    // for simulating getting the data
    let activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)

    // will contain an array of Cars and an array of Trucks
    var dataArray: [[Vehicle]] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        // empty view as footer so we don't see blank rows
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
    }
 
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.simulateGetData()
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let viewContainer = UIView()
        viewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let labelHeader = UILabel()
        
        labelHeader.textColor = UIColor.white
        if section == 0 {
            labelHeader.text = "Cars "
        }
        if section == 1 {
            labelHeader.text =  "Trucks"
        }
        viewContainer.addSubview(labelHeader)
        labelHeader.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        labelHeader.frame = viewContainer.frame
        
        return viewContainer
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray[section].count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCustomCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell

        let vehicle: Vehicle = dataArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.setData(vehicle)
        
        return cell
    }

    func simulateGetData() -> Void {
        
        // show the "spinner"
        view.addSubview(activityView)
        activityView.center = CGPoint(x: tableView.center.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y + 80)
        activityView.startAnimating()
        
        // simulate it taking 2 seconds to get the data
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.parseData(self.remoteData)
        }
    }
    
    func parseData(_ str: String) -> Void {
        
        var fullList: [Vehicle] = []
        
        // split retrieved string into lines
        let linesArray: [String] = str.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        linesArray.forEach { line in
            // split this line
            let a: [String] = line.components(separatedBy: ",")
            fullList.append(Vehicle(type: a[0] == "car" ? .car : .truck, brand: a[1], model: a[2]))
        }

        // get the cars
        var cars: [Vehicle] = fullList.filter { $0.type == .car }

        // get list of car brands
        let carBrands = Set((cars).compactMap { $0.brand })
        // for each brand, append a Vehicle with Brand but no Model
        carBrands.forEach { brand in
            cars.append(Vehicle(type: .car, brand: brand, model: ""))
        }
        
        // sort cars by brand / model
        cars.sort {
            ($0.brand, $0.model) <
                ($1.brand, $1.model)
        }
        
        // get the trucks and sort by brand / model
        var trucks: [Vehicle] = fullList.filter { $0.type == .truck }

        // get list of trueck brands
        let truckBrands = Set((trucks).compactMap { $0.brand })
        // for each brand, append a Vehicle with Brand but no Model
        truckBrands.forEach { brand in
            trucks.append(Vehicle(type: .truck, brand: brand, model: ""))
        }
        
        // sort trucks by brand / model
        trucks.sort {
            ($0.brand, $0.model) <
                ($1.brand, $1.model)
        }
        
        // fill our dataArray
        dataArray.append(cars)
        dataArray.append(trucks)
        
        // remove the spinner
        activityView.stopAnimating()
        activityView.removeFromSuperview()
        
        // reload the table
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    let remoteData: String = """
car,Chevrolet,Camaro
car,Chevrolet,Corvette
car,Chevrolet,Impala
car,Chevrolet,Malibu
car,Chevrolet,Sonic
truck,Chevrolet,Colorado
truck,Chevrolet,Silverado
car,Ford,EcoSport
car,Ford,Edge
car,Ford,Escape
car,Ford,Expedition
car,Ford,Fusion
car,Ford,Mustang
truck,Ford,F-150
truck,Ford,F-250
truck,Ford,F-350
car,Toyota,4Runner
car,Toyota,Avalon
car,Toyota,Camry
car,Toyota,Corolla
car,Toyota,Highlander
car,Toyota,Prius
car,Toyota,Rav4
truck,Toyota,Tacoma
truck,Toyota,Tundra
"""
    
}
```

and the source for the Storyboard I used with the Prototype cell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="wBJ-BC-ngb">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Multi Section View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="vJm-85-LPr">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="wBJ-BC-ngb" customClass="MultiSectionViewController" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="pxy-Ko-DBo">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="UEv-mW-XVy">
                                <rect key="frame" x="40" y="100" width="295" height="527"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                                <prototypes>
                                    <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="myCustomCell" id="rtS-G4-74c" customClass="MyCustomCell" customModule="MiniScratch" customModuleProvider="target">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="295" height="43.5"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                        <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="rtS-G4-74c" id="39C-jc-tSh">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="295" height="43.5"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <subviews>
                                                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KlT-QG-nQC">
                                                    <rect key="frame" x="15" y="11" width="265" height="21.5"/>
                                                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                    <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                </label>
                                            </subviews>
                                            <constraints>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="KlT-QG-nQC" secondAttribute="trailing" id="EpN-7X-Ue5"/>
                                                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="KlT-QG-nQC" secondAttribute="bottom" id="WK9-gS-0S3"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="KlT-QG-nQC" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="39C-jc-tSh" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="hkl-1J-cH5"/>
                                                <constraint firstItem="KlT-QG-nQC" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="39C-jc-tSh" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="zza-OX-VlC"/>
                                            </constraints>
                                        </tableViewCellContentView>
                                        <connections>
                                            <outlet property="labelLeading" destination="zza-OX-VlC" id="FIW-Qy-k9n"/>
                                            <outlet property="theLabel" destination="KlT-QG-nQC" id="CX2-4G-IlT"/>
                                        </connections>
                                    </tableViewCell>
                                </prototypes>
                            </tableView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="nNy-q0-wea" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="UEv-mW-XVy" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="Je2-cL-xF0"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="UEv-mW-XVy" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="nNy-q0-wea" secondAttribute="top" constant="100" id="Wne-7o-FQB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="nNy-q0-wea" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="UEv-mW-XVy" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="40" id="h4R-46-NsF"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="UEv-mW-XVy" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="nNy-q0-wea" secondAttribute="leading" constant="40" id="hUZ-2G-yQI"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="nNy-q0-wea"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableView" destination="UEv-mW-XVy" id="pMr-41-iIc"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="mYD-E0-bHz" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="52" y="-68"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice example.