# Multiple headerview in tableview in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to create 3 headers in the tableview given in the images and 8 students in each row, my code is as follows

[Screenshot of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zynoj.png)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var schoolOfList: [Any] = [
    [["school": ["VIP", "Bright International", "Motherland"]],
    [["student1": ["Chirag", "Akshay", "Shailesh", "Vishal", "Mehul", "Vinod", "Mukesh", "Darshan"]],
    ["student2": ["Manjari", "Kairav", "Abhimanyu", "Akshara", "Arohi", "Neel", "Naksh", "Naman"]],
    ["student3": ["Paritosh", "Anuj", "Kavya", "Samar", "Vanraj", "Kinjal", "Anupama", "Riyan"]]]]]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mytableview : UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> (Int) {
    return schoolOfList.count  
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for:indexPath)
   
    cell.textLabel?.text = schoolOfList["school"] as! [String]indexPath.row
    return cell
   }

    func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
      
        let headerview = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.mytableview.frame.width,height:50))
        headerview.backgroundColor = .green
        let lable = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.mytableview.frame.width,height:50))
        lable.textAlignment = .center
        lable.text = (schoolOfList["school"]as!String)
        headerview.addSubview(lable)
        return  headerview
}
```

Comment: does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63037795/multi-header-sections-in-uitableview-swift