# FloatingPanel not appearing - Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, panel, floating

I have a view controller which contains a table view. In this view controller, I've also set up a floating panel. The floating panel is not appearing for some reason, however. I know the ContentViewController is working, so I didn't include that code. The error is somewhere in this code and I can't find it. It's like the FloatingPanel is just not being added to the view.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import FloatingPanel

class Section {
    let title: String
    let options: [String]
    var isOpened: Bool = false
    
    init(title: String,
         options: [String],
         isOpened: Bool
    ) {
        self.title = title
        self.options = options
        self.isOpened = isOpened
    }
    
}

class PicsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate, FloatingPanelControllerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var addButton: UIButton!
    
    
    private let picsTableView: UITableView = {
        let picsTableView = UITableView()
        picsTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                               forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return picsTableView
    }()
    
    private var sections = [Section]()
    let backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    
    
    /*------------START FLOATING PANEL-------------*/
    var fpc: FloatingPanelController!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("PicsViewController LAUNCHED!!")
        fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.delegate = self
//        guard let contentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "fpc_content") as? ContentViewController else {
//            print("Failed to instantiate storyboard")
//            return
//        }
        let contentVC = ContentViewController()
        
        fpc.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
//        fpc.track(scrollView: contentVC.collectionView)
        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)
        
    /*------------END FLOATING PANEL-------------*/
        
        
        // Set up models
        picsTableView.delegate = self
        picsTableView.dataSource = self
        picsTableView.frame = view.bounds
        picsTableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.addSubview(picsTableView)
        sections = [
            Section(title: "Section 1", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false),
            Section(title: "Section 2", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false),
            Section(title: "Section 3", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false),
            Section(title: "Section 4", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false)
        ]
        // get rid of extra table view cells
        picsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        
        // customize button
        addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * addButton.bounds.size.width
        addButton.clipsToBounds = true
        addButton.backgroundColor = .red
        addButton.tintColor = .white
        addButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus-5-512"), for: .normal)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(addButton)
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Add button tapped")
    }
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let section = sections[section]
        
        if section.isOpened {
            return section.options.count + 1
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = picsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "cell",
            for: indexPath
        )
        cell.backgroundColor = .clear
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = .black
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].title
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].options[indexPath.row - 1]
        }
        
        return cell
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        picsTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            sections[indexPath.section].isOpened = !sections[indexPath.section].isOpened
            picsTableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .none)
        } else {
            print("Tapped sub cell \(indexPath.row)")
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted? Did it work? Are you still facing any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, 3 or 4 statements to add any view controller as subview  to any view controllers are

```
        let viewController = SomeViewController()
        self.addChild(viewController)
        self.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Because you havent provided the implementation for `addPanel` where you are calling `fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)`, I assume it does something similar to what I have written above, if I were to write it, I might write something like

```
    func addPanel(toParent: UIViewController) {
        toParent.addChild(self)
        toParent.view.addSubview(self.view)
        //add constraints or set frames for your subview
        self.didMove(toParent: toParent)
    }
```

Finally, you are adding multiple view's to your view controller's view namely a floating panel, tableView, and a button. Because you add panel before you add all other views it might be hidden under other subviews like `tableView`, you can obviously check this hypothesis using view debugger, and simplest way to fix it would be to use `bringSubviewToFront`, but issue is you are not holding the reference of `FloatingPanelController`'s view so you can try adding `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(fpc.view)` as last statement of `ViewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // all other codes of yours
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(fpc.view)
}
```

and for some reason if that doesnt work call `fpc.addPanel(toParent: self)` as last statement of `ViewDidLoad` instead of adding in between and add `bringSubviewToFront` as last statement of `addPanel(toParent` method

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("PicsViewController LAUNCHED!!")
        fpc = FloatingPanelController()
        fpc.delegate = self
        let contentVC = ContentViewController()

        fpc.set(contentViewController: contentVC)
        picsTableView.delegate = self
        picsTableView.dataSource = self
        picsTableView.frame = view.bounds
        picsTableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        view.addSubview(picsTableView)
        sections = [
            Section(title: "Section 1", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false),
            Section(title: "Section 2", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false),
            Section(title: "Section 3", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false),
            Section(title: "Section 4", options: ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], isOpened: false)
        ]
        // get rid of extra table view cells
        picsTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        // customize button
        addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * addButton.bounds.size.width
        addButton.clipsToBounds = true
        addButton.backgroundColor = .red
        addButton.tintColor = .white
        addButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus-5-512"), for: .normal)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(addButton)

        fpc.addPanel(toParent: self) //added as last statement
    }
```

and

```
func addPanel(toParent: UIViewController) {
        toParent.addChild(self)
        toParent.view.addSubview(self.view)
        self.didMove(toParent: toParent)
        toParent.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also have another question that I'm needing help on that I've posted. It's kind of paused progression of my app. Can you take a look at it too and see if it's something you'd be able to help with? No one seems to be responding. It's the question about creating Sub-section headers for a tableview.

Comment: Hi I am afk right now will take a look once am back

Comment: Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66621679/tableview-row-divider-headers-swift-xcode

Comment: @christian-w: Checkedout your question, the reason people are not responding is because typically in SO people expect you to post what have you tried so far and if you are stuck with something or doing something wrong people will help you out, but questions in which no code is added or shows no effort makes questions look like here is what I need now give me code :) and thats definitely not how SO works :) that being said you are expecting 3 levels of data revealing pattern isnt it? Like  sprots -> American sports -> Base ball, can you update your question and add how does your data looks like

Comment: How are you planning to drive this multiple double clicks (hierarchy) in data models? because you probably need hide/reveal rows on tap, you need expand and collapsing cells and section headers, again cant code unless you show us how have you formatted data so far? and what have you implemented as of now. If you have no idea where to start read : https://medium.com/@jeantimex/how-to-implement-collapsible-table-section-in-ios-142e0c6266fd https://programmingwithswift.com/expand-collapse-uitableview-section-with-swift/

Comment: if you can update the question add how your data looks like and write fundamental tableview code to populate it Ill take a look and help you with it further :) feel free to ping me if you get stuck following the tutorial or get stuck in custom implementation

Comment: Okay, I'll update it here in just a little! This is what I'm trying to do, except make sure the sub-headers don't have an action... only the sections (which expand when you tap them) and the individual cells. I just don't understand how he set up the data model... like the structs and variable arrays n such. https://sapandiwakar.in/nested-sections-in-uitableview/

Comment: This is it as well, but notice they don't explain how to setup your variable arrays and stuff. I'm lost trying to figure out whether it's multiple arrays... one array... an array of structs... is it an array of an array of an array...?? Also, the code on the Stack overflow version (scroll down to the Swift post) has some issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650243/uitableview-nested-section-headers

Comment: Essentially, I'm just trying to set it up either how they have it set up in their code, or similarly. I need help figuring out how to set up the variables (for example, the two named: sections, sectionHeaders) though.

Comment: Hey it's well over midnight here, I'll login tomorrow please update the question with code n whatever you tried so far if someone helps great else I'll give it a try tomorrow morning

Comment: Sorry, I had midterms that were kicking my butt for 14 hours yesterday. Thank you ahead of time for your help!! Here is the updated StackOverflow article: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66621679/13062902

Comment: I also updated the article body itself with any pertinent information just now. I think I explained my goal pretty well and provided the code that is supposedly the route to go. I included links to the articles which I obtained the code from in case you don't understand it. Thanks!

Comment: @christian-w: Its almost 12 AM now, logging off for today, I checked your question couple of days ago it wasnt updated so I did not comment will check tomorrow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230046/discussion-between-christian-w-and-sandeep-bhandari).

Comment: Any luck on the tableview?